# Cannot access Request Body in FoalTS hooks

Tags: javascript, typescript, logging, foalts

I am trying to log request data from an API endpoint to ensure we have periodic backups for when the database crashes in between backup intervals. A logging hook has been created and attached to the controller where I access the `Context` variable as `ctx`.  I have been able to access the request user through `ctx.user`  but the body is undefined whenever I try to access it through `ctx.request.body`

To my knowledge vanilla JS requests have a `.clone()` method that clones the `request` because the request body is destroyed on use. My approach is to make a hook that logs the data in a file and writes to disk but so far the body showing up empty in the logging hook.

attempts to resolve:

- copy context as in `ctx2 = ctx` and use `ctx2` in the controller
- copy context as in `ctx2 = { ...ctx  }` and use `ctx2`in the controller
- read node docs, no reference of a clone method.
- set ctx.body to the body variable being used in the controller

is there anything being overlooked?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're accessing the request body using the wrong key.

The request body is accessible through `ctx.request.body` and not `ctx.body`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typo on my end, correcting